# Variable to hold the return of type wrapper class from a method

Tags: apex, visualforce, wrapper-class, inner-class

I have a class and a method. In the method I am calling another method of another class - Class2.Method2
The return type of method 2 is a wrapper class. What should be the variable type in my method 1 to hold this returning wrapper class from the method 2 ?

Comment: Please include the entire error message *verbatim* as well as the code snippet you use which generates the error.

Comment: It'll also be important to know whether your wrapper class is a standalone class, or an inner class of another class. You can [edit] your question to include those extra details (comments are temporary, limited in length, and limited in formatting options).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fully qualified type name is `OuterClass.InnerClass`. In your case, your outer class is `WrapperClassTeest` (sic) and your inner class is `wrapperClass`. Therefore, you would do

```
WraperClassTeest.WrapperClass instance = WrapperClassTTeest.methodToReturnWrapper();
```